# How can I get Agent Ransack to return one line above and below match?

Tags: windows-search, agent-ransack

I want to see the matches in context of the lines above and below the match.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Do you have screen shots to outline it?

Comment: Just perform any search in Agent Ransack.  The results show only the line containing the search text.  I'm trying to see one line above and one line below the line containing the text

Comment: As you can't adjust the software I can only think you can ask the company that made Agent Ransack. As a temporary alternative you can just walk through the lines using your up and down arrow keys, where you can see the lines before and after in the right side of the application.

Comment: I posted to see if there was an out-of-the-box way to do this (perhaps an option I was missing).  Seems not, so I can just contact the company.  Thanks!

Comment: Tom - can you post your comment as the answer so I can accept and give you credit?

Comment: Done! If they ever implement this, feel free to unaccept and post your own answer... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After talking with AgentRansack developers:

> That's an option we reserve for the Pro version (FileLocator Pro):
> http://mythicsoft.com/agentransack/features
>
> We need to differentiate the two products and it's features like this that are reserved.

"Data Discovery -> Show surrounding lines"

So that means they will probably never add it to AgentRansack...

Answer (score 1):

As you can't adjust the software I can only think you can ask the company that made Agent Ransack. As a temporary alternative you can just walk through the lines using your up and down arrow keys, where you can see the lines before and after in the right side of the application.